# Iterator error in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a adapter class which provides an interface for priority queue using set.

```
#include<set>
using namespace std;

template<typename PRIO,typename VALUE >
class Adapter 
{
    //a typedef for a type "item", which acts as a pointer to an element in the queue
    //(item is used below in various methods).

    template<typename PR,typename VAL>
    class Node{
    public:
            PR prio;
            VAL value;
                    Node(PR p,VAL v) : prio(p),value(v) {}
    };

    set< Node<PRIO,VALUE> > queue;

    public:
    typedef typename set< Node<PRIO,VALUE> >::iterator item;

    // inserts a new element
    item insert(const PRIO &prio, const VALUE &value) 
    { 
        Node<PRIO,VALUE> temp(prio,value);
        return (queue.insert(temp)).first;
    }

    // decreases the priority of item to prio
    item decPrio(item& it, const PRIO &prio)     //CHANGED !!!!
    {
        Node<PRIO,VALUE> temp(prio,it->value);
        queue.erase(it);
        it=queue.insert(temp);

    }

    // returns the minimum element
    item findMin() const {return queue.begin();}

};
```

When I compiling the code, I'm getting the error, no match for operator = in `it`(The variable in decPrio). There is also some error related to std::less. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
    Node<PRIO,VALUE> temp(prio,item->value);
```

`item` is a type.  Perhaps you meant:

```
    Node<PRIO,VALUE> temp(prio,it->value);
```

Comment: @user3349665: After that change, the code compiles fine as-is: https://ideone.com/J2T7UR  Maybe the problem is in other code you are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::set` needs a comparison function object to weed out duplicate objects. This function object is passed in as an optional second template parameter to `std::set`:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
};

std::set<Foo> foo_set; // <-- Error: doesn't know how to compare two MyType objects

struct FooCompare {
    bool operator()( const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs ) const { 
        return lhs.x < rhs.x;
    }
};

std::set<Foo, FooCompare> foo_set; // <-- Works: set uses FooCompare to compare two Foo objects
```

By default, this comparison function object is set to `std::less` specialized with the value type of the set. `std::less` in turn calls `operator<` on the value type of the set.

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    bool operator<( const Foo& rhs ) const {
        return x < rhs.x;
    }
};

std::set<Foo> foo_set; // Works!
```

This is where your error message comes in. You have no `operator<` defined for your `Node` class, and C++ has no way of determining how you want your `Node` objects compared. Simply adding an `operator<` to your `Node` class will solve the issue. Alternatively, you can create a `Node` comparison function object and pass that in as the second template argument to your `std::set` as shown in the example above.